# Issue with observable fork join

Tags: sqlite, angular, reactjs, observable, ionic3

Hi I have 3 tables of which, each one is child of another. I wrote a method to fetch from sqllite db as follows

```
public downloadFromOfflineDB(db,testSO){
           var observableBatch = [];
           observableBatch.push(db.executeSql("select * from TMP_AUD WHERE CRE_BY=? AND AUD_NUMBER=? ",
                        [localStorage.getItem("user_name"), testSO.auditNumber]).then(
                        response => {
                            this._util.logData('In downloadPendingInstancesForSyncFromOfflineDB- folder'+response.rows.length+'ID= '+response.rows.item(0).FLD_NUMBER);
                            if (response && response.rows && response.rows.length > 0) {
                                if (response && response.rows && response.rows.length > 0) {
                                    var FLD_NUMBER = response.rows.item(0).FLD_NUMBER;
                                    var folderArray = []
                                    observableBatch.push(db.executeSql("select * from TMP_FOLDER WHERE CRE_BY=? AND FLD_NUMBER=? ",
                                        [localStorage.getItem("user_name"), FLD_NUMBER]).then(
                                        a => {
                                              this._util.logData('In downloadPendingInstancesForSyncFromOfflineDB-TMP_FOLDER'+a.rows.length);
                                            if (a && a.rows && a.rows.length > 0) {
                                                for (let i = 0; i < a.rows.length; i++) {
                                                    var folderObj = {
                                                        folderName: a.rows.item(i).FLD_NAME,
                                                        files:[]
                                                    }

                                                    var FLD_NAME = a.rows.item(i).FLD_NAME
                                                   this._util.logData('In downloadPendingInstancesForSyncFromOfflineDB-TMP_FOLDER '+FLD_NAME);
                                                   observableBatch.push( db.executeSql("select * from TMP_FILES WHERE CRE_BY=? AND FLD_NAME=? ",
                                                        [localStorage.getItem("user_name"), FLD_NAME]).then(
                                                        b => {
                                                              this._util.logData('In downloadPendingInstancesForSyncFromOfflineDB-TMP_FILES'+b.rows.length);
                                                            var fileArray = [];
                                                            if (b && b.rows && b.rows.length > 0) {
                                                                for (let j = 0; j < b.rows.length; j++) {
                                                                    var fileSO = {
                                                                        compliance: b.rows.item(j).COMPLIANCE,
                                                                        remarks: b.rows.item(j).REMARKS,
                                                                        fileName: b.rows.item(j).FILE_NAME,
                                                                        title: b.rows.item(j).TITLE

                                                                        }

                                                                    );
                                                                   fileArray.push(fileSO);
                                                                }}
                                                             folderObj.files=fileArray;
                                                            }).catch(
                                                                            e => {
                                                                                this._util.logData('For sync error'+JSON.stringify(e));
                                                                                return Observable.throw("An error occurred during sync");
                                                                            })
                                                            );

                                                        folderArray.push(folderObj);
                                                }}

                                        }).catch(
                                                    e => {
                                                        this._util.logData('For sync error'+JSON.stringify(e));
                                                        return Observable.throw("An error occurred during sync");
                                                    })
                                        );
                                }


                            }
                            testSO.folderArray = folderArray;
                            this._util.logData('Candidate for selected for sync' + JSON.stringify(testSO));

                        })
           );
        return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch);
    }
```

The issue here is below method is not waiting for all the calls to finish

```
 public getFiles(testSO) {

        return Observable.create(observer => {

            this.platform.ready().then(() => {
                this.sqlite.create({
                    name: 'offline.db',
                    location: 'default'
                }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
                    this.downloadFromOfflineDB(db, testSO).subscribe(c => {
                        observer.next(c[0]);//This is undefined
                        observer.complete();
                    },
                    error => {

                        observer.error("An error occurred sync files.");                                                                                        
                    });

                 });
            });
        });
    }
```

First method is executing, while second method returns before first execution is complete and I am not getting my object testSO populated. Can someone please guide me and tel me what I am doing wrong here.I used observable fork Join.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling `Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch)` with only one item - result of `db.executeSql`. When you add more items later on it doesn't affect `forkJoin`.

Comment: observableBatch is array to which I am pushing all the db.executeSql functions. Since db.executeSql returns promise. So i did it in below fashion  observableBatch.push(Observable.fromPromise(db.executeSql(..))) and tried. But no luck

Comment: @jslearn07, Again, you are adding promises to `observableBatch` when forkJoin is already called so it won't wait for them.

Comment: so u mean to say i should return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch) at the then of last statement? I followed this example http://techqa.info/programming/question/35676451/observable.forkjoin-and-array-argument. if possible can you please post the code.

Comment: @jslearner07, Actually I am saying that you can't use `forkJoin` when your next task depends on result of your previous task. If you reproduce the problem on the [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/), [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or alike then I will fix it for you.

Comment: may be what you said is right. However I changed my implementation to something like, I kept a common identifier for 3 tables. I do sequential querying of 3 tables using this common identifier and each of them return promise and finally I will consolidate all results internally by comparing the parent id and create the json. This way I got the above impl work. Thanks.